# Marketing cloud IP Allowlisting

Tags: marketing-cloud

Regarding Marketing cloud, our business unit has security settings as follows.

Login Expires After Inactivity|`Never Expires`

Invalid Logins Before Lockout|`3`

Minimum Username Length|`6 characters`

Restrict Logins by IP Address (IP Allowlisting)|`IP Allowlisting Disabled`

IP Allowlisting List Source|`Defined at Business Unit level`

Allow machines not on Allowlisted IP Addresses list access|`No`

Identity Verification|`Yes`

Business Unit Identity Verification|`Use Business Unit Setting`

Browser Verification Code Lifetime|`30 minutes`

Time a browser can be inactive before requiring re-verification|`90 Days`

Do not require Identity Verification for machines inside the allowlist|`No`

Enable Username and Password for Web Services|`No`

We would like to enable the option of IP Allowlisting.
Is that effect to all Business Units or just applied on our Business Unit?
Also, if we set IP Allowlisting, we also needed to add into our allowlist.
Is that all domains of allowlist that we need to allowlist follows?

```
    bounce.exacttarget.com
    exacttarget.com
    *.marketingcloudapps.com
    verify.salesforce.com (for multi-factor authentication use)
```

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion.htm&type=5
I found the content on the website.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted, if it has been helpful

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two different things. The link you are referring to are all the IP addresses OF Marketing Cloud (SFMC). These need to be whitelisted in e.g. your firewall or any other applications which need to communicate with SFMC. These have nothing to do with the security setting of Login IP Allowlist. This list defines the IP addresses from which users are allowed to log in to SFMC.

If you read the [correct documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_ip_allowlist.htm&type=5), it clearly states that:

> Define different IP ranges for each Business Unit or allowlist IP
> ranges at the Enterprise level and force the business unit to inherit
> the parent settings.

Hence you can choose if these apply to one or all business units.